# Achar menor valor em vetor recursivamente

Tags: c

Minha função recursiva precisa retornar o menor vetor, só que está retornando sempre 0. O que está errado na minha lógica?

Minha função:

```
int menor(int vet[], int i)  
{
int m=0;

if(vet[i] == 0)
{
    m=vet[i];
    return m;
}

if( vet[i] < m)
{
    m=vet[i];

}

return menor(vet,i-1);

}

int main()
{
int vetor[]= {1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17};

m=menor(vetor,7);

printf("%d\n",m );
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode implementar uma função que recebe um vetor de inteiros e seu respectivo tamanho e retorna o menor valor encontrando dentro deste vetor, veja só:

```
int menor( int vec[], int tam )
{
    if( tam == 1 )
        return vec[0];

    int m = menor( vec + 1, tam - 1 );

    return ( vec[0] < m ) ? vec[0] : m;
}
```

Testando:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int menor( int vec[], int tam )
{
    if( tam == 1 )
        return vec[0];

    int m = menor( vec + 1, tam - 1 );

    return ( vec[0] < m ) ? vec[0] : m;
}

int main( void )
{
    int vetor[]= {8,3,5,7,11,13,17,4,8,10};
    int tam = sizeof(vetor) / sizeof(int);

    int min = menor( vetor, tam );

    printf( "%d\n", min );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
3
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/P7PbVp)

Answer (score 5):

O que está acontecendo é que você está zerando o valor de `m` a cada iteração, logo sempre vai voltar `m=0`. Uma alternativa, é fazer de `m` um parâmetro da função, passado a cada iteração. Ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int menor(int vet[], int i, int m) {
  // Se tiver chegado já ao fim do array para o código
  if(i < 0) {
    return m;
  }
  // Verifica se o valor atual é menor que o MENOR valor salvo até então
  if(vet[i] < m) {
    m = vet[i];
  }
  // Chama a recursão
  return menor(vet, i-1, m);
}

int main() {
  int vetor[]= {8,2,3,5,7,11,13,17};
  // Adicionamos um parâmetro na chamada, no caso o último valor do vetor.
  int m = menor(vetor, 7, vetor[7]);
  printf("%d\n",m);
  return 0;
}
```

Perceba que começamos com um chute, que pertence ao vetor, do menor valor ao invés de começar com um valor pré-definido. A maneira que você tinha feito pode levar a comportamentos não esperados, por exemplo, e se nenhum valor fosse menor do que 0? 0 seria retornado e poderia nem mesmo pertencer ao vetor procurado.

Comment: Entendi, eu sempre tava zerando, obrigado mano.